# should bug and feature requests on Meta that are implemented/rejected be closed? (either automatically or manually)

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I'm new to Meta, so I'm just asking.  I see some feature request questions and also some bug report questions that have been worked to completion or rejected or whatever by the SO developers, but the questions remain open.

Is there a good reason to leave these questions open indefinitely?  Would it be worthwhile to write some code to automatically close the questions when the SO admin tags it as such?  Or maybe the other way around ... maybe the closure reasons can automatically get a special tag added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they need to be closed. I say they should stay open so that the community can continue to discuss at their leisure, whether that is discussing why it was rejected (and perhaps later on will be implemented) or discuss the success/failure of items that were implemented.

Comment: +1, Bugs/fixes can always have future issues for whatever reason, it's good to keep discussion for them available